# ASP.NET: Turning on errors

Tags: asp.net, web-config

This is what I see when I visit my web site. How do I instead get the Yellow Screen of Death so I know what the error is?

[image]

I have set customErrors to "off".

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your web config. You need to turn off custom errors.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: I've already got that, actually, under <system.web>. Is that correct?

Comment: You probably have done this but if you have been making modifications to web.config it is important to reset IIS

Comment: your right...oops to me and you. Yep, sometimes it just takes someone to talk to briefly for the solution to appear. +1 for you for seeing my mistake and yours.

Comment: You normally don't have to reset IIS if you change the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ELMAH. Here is the link

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 0):

You also may need to set debug to true:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive IIS is configured properly? Could be an Application Pool error, or a problem with the Handler Mappings, etc.

It looks like the error probably isn't with your code or web.config, but rather with the configuration of the site in IIS 7.